# Fetch data from sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table with four fields:

[image]

I want to fetch the data for RegionName(Pune, Delhi) or ProjectName(TPQ).
My expected result is Checklist4,checklist1, and checklist3.

How to write a SQLite query for this?

Comment: Have you searched? What have you tried? What did not work? What did you not understand? Could you show us some code of what you've tried? Have you searched? You post a question immediately while there are plenty of questions/tutorials about this on the internet and SO.

Comment: Did you mean "or" instead of "and"? Otherwise, you get zero rows returned

Comment: Check my answer.. if you have other questions related to it, comment there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your main issue is the SQL query where you actually mean to use the "OR" keyword and not "AND" as you have in your mind..

The "OR" keyword will return results that satisfy any of your criteria so either the RegionName can be one of the two values (Pune, Delhi) OR the ProjectName can be TPQ.

On the opposite, the "AND" keyword will return results that satisfy ALL of your criteria. In your table, in order to have a result returned, you should have for example a row where the RegionName is "Pune" AND the ProjectName is "TPQ".

Try the following assuming your table is called "TableName":

```
Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT CheckListName from TableName where RegionName IN ('Pune', 'Delhi') OR ProjectName ='TPQ'", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative query syntax (which I prefer) is:

```
String[] params = {"Pune", "Delhi", "TPQ"};
String query = "SELECT CheckListName FROM YourTableName WHERE RegionName IN (?, ?) OR ProjectName =?";

Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query, params);
```

Just replace `YourTableName` with the actual name of your table.

This not only handles the string values automatically (by adding the single quotes and doubling the apostrophes), but also fights SQL injection.

Note: the order of the parameters is **positional**. Meaning that the first placeholder (`?`) will be replaced by the first element in the parameter array and so on.